# Override image maximum width in theme (Using Gutenberg editor)

Tags: add-theme-support, block-editor

I recently installed [Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg) plugin to my Wordpress installation.
The [theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/reyl-lite/) I am using is not full width for posts. 
There's a "Wide" option for images in a post but the theme won't allow the image to go beyond the theme's rules.

I tried this [solution](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/extensibility/theme-support/#wide-images) (add theme support) offered by Gutenberg's team. But no luck.

```
add_theme_support( 'gutenberg', array(

// Theme supports wide images, galleries and videos.
'wide-images' => true,

// Make specific theme colors available in the editor.
'colors' => array(
    '#ffffff',
    '#000000',
    '#cccccc',
),
```

What should I search for in the code to start finding a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: If your theme doesn't support wide images, why are you telling Gutenberg that it does?

Answer (score 2):

`add_theme_support('gutenberg', ['wide-images' => true ])` is telling gutenberg, *hey this sites content area's CSS is setup to handle wide images.* The theme_support wide-images code isn't a magic fix - instead it's an aknowledgment from the theme developer to gutenberg, that the themes CSS's ready for gutenberg wide content.

--

If you're just experimenting, and only want that CSS change done to pages that use gutenberg, you can use a snippet like this to check if the page is gutenberg:

```
add_action('body_class', function($classes){
    if (function_exists('the_gutenberg_project') && gutenberg_post_has_blocks( get_the_ID() ) )
        $classes[] = 'using-gutenberg';
    return $classes;
});
```

The you can better select your elements for gutenberg only, making your CSS like

```
body.using-gutenberg #container.container {
    /* ..wtv full width css */
}
```

If you're curious about the how the content CSS is done, is in relation to Gutenberg, checkout the [gutenberg-starter-theme on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-starter-theme) for reference.

Comment: This isn't quite right. Wide images are for having images wider than the content area, and doesn't say anything about whether the content area is full width or not. If it were then a wide images option wouldn't be necessary. The reason you declare wide images support is to let Gutenberg know that your theme has CSS for the `alignwide` class on images. An example of how this class can be used is outlined in this article: https://themehybrid.com/weblog/align-wide-and-full-classes

Comment: my bad, i mixed up `alignfull` and `alignwide`. same principle, kinda.

Comment: ive edited the answer to reflect. thanks for pointing that out.